# In quantum field theory, are $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ still operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

It might be a silly question, but it originates from taking expectation values of the field operators, such as $$\ \langle 0| \phi(x) | 0 \rangle ,$$ in which there will be terms like: $$  \langle 0| ae^{-ip^{\mu}x_{\mu}} | 0 \rangle \hphantom{iii}\textit{and} \hphantom{iii}  \langle 0| a^{\dagger}e^{ip^{\mu}x_{\mu}} | 0 \rangle ,$$
where $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ are the annihilation and creation operators.

The question is, can I commute $e^{ip^{\mu}x_{\mu}}$ with $| 0 \rangle$ ?

I.e. is $p^{\mu}x_{\mu} = p \cdot x$ an operator or just a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the $x$ and $p$ coming from the field expansion in momentum eigenstates, then they are just numbers, hence they "commute" with everything else (as does their exponential of course). The "operatorial component" of the field operator is all in the creation/annihilation operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ (in your example of a real scalar field).

The expectation values you are referring to vanish because from the definition of the vacuum state $| 0 \rangle$ you have
$$ a | 0 \rangle =  0$$